# LOGIN Laravel 7 no funciona, pero registro si

Tags: laravel-7

sin ningún tipo de cambio en el codigo, donde ya edité y modifiqué el login personalizado y ha estado funcionando dos meses, de un momento a otro deja de funcionarme el login.

SIn embargo, si registro si me deja entrar con la redireccion automatica a la app, pero deslogeo y con ese mismo recien creado con el que he podido acceder, vuelvo a entrar desde login y no me da mensaje ni me deja, se queda en el formulario de login.

¿por donde puedo empezar a buscar la solución? no doy con ella, ir pidiendome partes de codigo y lo vemos, estoy estancado y es un proyecto a presentar pronto.-

LOGIN CONTROLLER

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }


}
```

Comment: Revisa si el log de Laravel tiene algo registrado referente al problema presentado y de ser así agregalo a la pregunta

Comment: Sería útil ver el código del login en tu controlador de usuarios. Puede que haya un caso de uso que no esté contemplado.

Comment: En el log de laravel no me da ningun error del login

Comment: El código va en la pregunta

Comment: listo ese es el codigo, en mi caso uso CIF para el acceso, funcionando durante dos meses hasta hace un rato ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

analizando y organizando el código parece que lo he solucionado.

En AuthenticatesUsers hay una funcion:

```
public function username()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
```

Por algun motivo que desconozco, a no ser que al actualizar composer se haya cambiado solo, donde pone user yo estaba usando CIF. Al cambiarlo de nuevo, ya me deja acceder de nuevo sin problemas.

Gracias.

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita